# Depending on the newest cookie, do something

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I'm using a plug in to create, read, and delete cookies (see below). With this, I'm creating 4 different types of cookies. For example, if they reach the page...

1) abc.com/A.html, do...

```
createCookieSS("cookieA", 1, 365);
```

2) abc.com/B.html, do...

```
createCookieSS("cookieB", 1, 365);
```

... and so on. Knowing that, a person could have a max of 4 different cookies while they are on the site.

What I want to achieve is depending on whichever cookie is the newest and if they land on the homepage, they will see a banner depending on the newest cookie.

Is that something that's doable?

Appreciate the insight!

---

Cookie plug in

```
function createCookieSS(name,value,days) {
  if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
  }
  else var expires = "";
  document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookieSS(name) {
  var nameEQ = name + "=";
  var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
  for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
  }
  return null;
}

function deleteCookieSS(name){
  document.cookie = name +"=; path=/; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT";
}
```

Comment: Note this is  simpler using localStorage instead of cookies

Comment: Hi Charlietfl - if I am using localStorage instead of cookie, how would I go about checking the newest localStorage key (assuming there are 4) and if they land on the homepage, show them a banner? Thanks!

Comment: If it was me would store one array of objects with {date, banner} in each object. Then is a simple sort by date and take first one or use `Array#reduce()`